# Setar Propriedade Enabled do ActionList para True

Tags: delphi, actions

Eu armazeno em uma tabela o nome das minhas Actions, e de forma dinâmica através de uma query, eu retorno elas em tela, da seguinte forma:

declaro uma variavel do tipo:

```
MinhaACL : TAction;

Begin
   MinhaACL := TAction(qryActions.FieldByName('nomeacl').Asstring);
   MinhaACL.Enabled := True;
End;
```

Porém quando eu tento Ativar ela com o Enable, o sistema mostra o seguinte erro:

> Access violation at address 3B90C301 in module 'BetterFuell.exe'. Read
>   of address 3B90C301

Tem alguma outra forma de eu fazer isso ? Se alguém puder me dar uma Luz.

OBS:
E ja tentei colocar assim

```
MinhaACL := TAction('NomeDaMinhaACL'); 
MinhaACL.Enabled := True;
```

Comment: Não, ja testei, ela está retornando os dados.

Dei um ShowMessage(qryActions.FieldByName('nomeacl').Asstring) e retorna os dados corretamente.

E ja tentei colocar assim

   MinhaACL := TAction('NomeDaMinhaACL');
   MinhaACL.Enabled := True;

E retorna com o mesmo erro

Comment: Estás a tentar converter uma string para um objecto TAction... claro que dá erro. Tens de usar a string para procurar a action, talvez pelos componentes do teu form, por exemplo.

Comment: @tiago-rodrigues, você teria um exemplo de como localizar uma action através de uma string ?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que voce tem o nome da action mas nao o pode converter diretamente para um object do tipo TAction. Assumindo que as suas Actions estao dentro de uma TActionList (corrija-me se estiver enganado), pode fazer uma funçao para receber o nome de uma TAction, fazer o loop da TActionList e devolver a TAction que tiver o nome pretendido. Algo como

```
function FindActionByName(SearchName:String;ActionList:TActionList):TAction;
var
  at:TAction;
  a: Integer;
begin
  result:=nil;
  for a := 0 to ActionList.ActionCount-1 do
    if ActionList[a].Name=SearchName then
    begin
      result:= TAction(ActionList[a]);
      break;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certinho aqui @tiago-rodrigues.

Answer (score 0):

Código completo conforme ajuda recebida:

```
procedure TMainForm.ValidaFormsLiberados;
var
 // Declarei as variáveis necessárias
  ArrQtdReg : Array of string;
  Registros, i, a: Integer;
  ChaveACL : string;
begin
  // Buscando Registros na minha query
  with qryPermitidos do
    begin
      Close;
      Open;
      Last;
      First;
    end;

  with qryFormsLocate do
    begin
      Close;
      Open;
    end;

    // Contando Registros
    Registros := qryPermitidos.RecordCount;
    SetLength(ArrQtdReg, Registros);

    // Desativando todas as minhas Actions
    for a := 0 to aclMenuPrincipal.ActionCount-1 do
      begin
        TCustomAction(aclMenuPrincipal.Actions[a]).Visible := False;
      end;


    // Liberando somente as Actions cadastradas na minha Query

    for I := 1 to Registros do
      begin
          ChaveACL          := qryPermitidosform_actionlist.AsString;
          ArrQtdReg[I]      := 'String '+ChaveACL;
          qryPermitidos.Next;

          for a := 0 to aclMenuPrincipal.ActionCount-1 do
            if aclMenuPrincipal[a].Name=ChaveACL then
            begin
              TCustomAction(aclMenuPrincipal.Actions[a]).Visible := True;
              break;
            end;
      end;

end;
```

Depois só chamei minha procedure ao criar meu formulario principal.

Grato ao Tiago Rodrigues pela ajuda.